# Could not find or load main class oracle.assistants.dbca.driver.DBConfigurator

Tags: database, oracle, dbca

I tried to run dbca on Linux 4.1.12-61.1.27.el7uek.x86_64 x86_64, Oracle Database 12C. Unfortunately the following error appeared: Could not find or load main class oracle.assistants.dbca.driver.DBConfigurator. Could someone help in this case? environment variables: ORACLE_HOME,DISPALY,ORACLE_BASE and PATH are set.

Answer (score 1):

try the following:

```
cd $ORACLE_HOME/bin
```

then either

```
./dbca
```

or

```
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/dbca
```